# Iterate dict of dict of dict in python

Tags: python

I have dict on dict of dict . And I want  a function which will return all the details if arguement matches the key like,

```
identifiers = {
     '42566431313931326462642d3533656132352033': {         
         'name': 'topleft',         
         'subid': {
            'a3e54b84450000': {
                'name': 'north'                
            }
        }        
    },
    '0942378098093': {         
         'name': 'topright',         
         'subid': {
            '4b840000100000000000': {
                'name': 'north'                
            }
        }        
    },
    '4256643131ra98892389': {         
         'name': 'bottomleft',         
         'subid': {
            'a3e54b840000100000000000': {
                'name': 'west'                
            }
        }        
    }
}

def getdetails(p):
    # p could be key of dict or dict of dict
    for key in identifiers:
        if key == p:
            return identifiers[key]        
        else:
            if p in identifiers[key]['subid']:
                return identifiers[key]['subid'][p]
```

I want to know if there is elegent way to do it (May be using map and lambda)?

Comment: What is `d` and why are you overwriting `key`?

Comment: Is `identifier` different from `identifiers`?

Comment: Tip: using `//` for comments in python raises a syntaxerror

Comment: Now, your comment says `id` but it is not used anywhere.

Comment: Also Python's function will not work with `{}`

Comment: @thefourtheye extremely sorry

Comment: The only improvement I could suggest readily is, combine the `else` and `if` sections together.

Comment: can you add example iutput and output for getdetails?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Readability is important. As your code is readable, I would improve the code slightly, like this

```
def getdetails(p):
    if p in ids:
        return ids[p]

    for k, v in ids.iteritems():
        if p in v['subid']:
            return v['subid'][p]
```

But if you are looking for one-liners, you can create a generator expression and return the first value got from that.

```
def getdetails(p):
    if p in ids: return ids[p]
    return next(v['subid'][p] for k, v in ids.iteritems() if p in v['subid'])
```

You can further shorten the code, like this

```
def getdetails(p):
    return ids.get(p) or next(v['subid'][p] for k, v in ids.iteritems() if p in v['subid'])
```

The `dict.get` will return `None` if the key is not found in the dictionary and that is considered Falsy in Python. So, if it is not in the main dictionary, we will check in the sub dictionaries.

If you are using Python 3.x, you need to use `items` method instead of `iteritems`, like this

```
def getdetails(p):
    return ids.get(p) or next(v['subid'][p] for k, v in ids.items() if p in v['subid'])
```

Comment: @Pilot What should be the output for `a3e54b840000100000000000`?

Comment: @Pilot But there are two items matching the same id. Both `north` and `west`. Are you sure you want only the `west`?

Answer (score 2):

```
for key,value in identifiers.items():
        if key == p:
            return identifiers[key]        
        else:
            if p in identifiers[key]['subid']:
                return identifiers[key]['subid'][p]
```

Answer (score 2):

If you are sure `p` to be inside `subid` if not in top level may be something like below would work as well.

```
def getdetails(p):
    req_val = identifiers.get(p)
    if not req_val:
       for key, value in identifiers.items():
            req_val = value['subid'].get(p)
    return req_val
```

Answer (score 2):

Try recursion like this:

```
def getdetails(p, dictionary):
    result = []
    if type(dictionary) is not dict:
        return result
    for key in dictionary:
        if key == p:
            result.append(dictionary[p])
        result += getdetails(p, dictionary[key])

    return result

print getdetails('name', identifiers)
print getdetails('subid', identifiers)
```